# SSAS Dimension Security with SQL Stored Procedure not showing all data

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, cube

I implemented SSAS dimension security based on a .NET assembly that calls a Stored Procedure setting it to the allowed dimension set, using the USER as an expression.

I implemented this security on two dimensions.

it's something like Tasks and Projects

I have two fact tables one related to tasks and other related to Projects

All that would be simple, the tricky part is that tasks are related to projects, and the tasks dimension relates to the projects fact table, however not all projects must have a task related.

Tasks are also related to projects so the tasks dimension cross the projects fact table.

This all works but when testing I noticed the data returned is not all the data the user should have access to, so I built up a Log table that logged the set that the .net assembly would return, the user who's accessing the cube and the number of members the user have access to.

I tested it and the log table register correctly:

- User Rows  SET
- UserA 103 {....}

However only 20 rows of data are displayed.

When I removed the NON EMPTY clause of the MDX all the rows appeared, however the values where NULL

I digged out a little and found out that the issue was on the dimension crossing the fact table, when I removed those mentioned crossings all data was revealed.

Thanks in advance.
Gabriel Guimarães

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like everything is working as designed...that is the correct behavior for NON EMPTY...it's like adding a filter for WHERE xxx IS NOT NULL.

Or are you saying there should be values where you see nulls after removing the NON EMPTY clause?

Comment: nope, I've updated the question, I found out that the error is not related to the NON EMPTY clause.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the the cube structure and dimension usage tab to help me better understand how this is modeled?